# Red Line at bottom of video sequencer gone in new update

Tags: video-sequence-editor, cache

[image: Video Sequencer]

Hey guys their used to be this red line at the bottom of the video sequencer that isnt there anymore in the most recent blender update, do you guys know how to get it back? it was super useful for just scrubbing through and making the animation render quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switch the drawing on in the View menu(Check: Show Cache and Final Images):

[image]

You select, what you want it to show here:

[image]

And if you want it to prefetch, you check that here:

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much!!! is their anyway to have it so it automatically has the cache final images on all the time, when i open a new file i have to go and manually do it again

Comment: If you set it up the way you want it you can go to: File Defaults Save Startup Settings. And it'll have the settings you want each time you start a new project.

Comment: @ValentinoValentine If your question has been answered, please mark the answer accordingly.